# How do I disable image zooming on phonegap/cordova when image is tapped?

Tags: ios, image, cordova

I have a phonegap/cordova application that pulls blog posts from a wordpress website. However, I have a problem that when an image on a page is tapped, it opens up fullscreen, which hides the navigation of the app. This behavior is less than ideal, since the user has to exit the app and reopen it to get the navigation controls back.

Here is a screenshot of the behavior using the iOS simulator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLl4H.jpg

The behavior also occurs on iPad Air 2.

Is there a way to disable this behavior in phonegap/cordova?

Comment: just change the behaviour of the tap on the image to not open it

Comment: Thanks for that. I changed the behavior of the link not to go to the URL by default, see answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code was in this format:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="attachment_38739" style="width: 310px" class="wp-caption alignright"><a href="http://unfspinnaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/BodyFound_GarrettMilanovich_3.jpg" class="ui-link"><img class="wp-image-38739 size-medium" src="http://unfspinnaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/BodyFound_GarrettMilanovich_3-300x200.jpg" alt="The body will be sent to the medical examiner’s office for further investigation.    Photo by Garrett Milanovich " width="300" height="200"></a><p class="wp-caption-text">The body will be sent to the medical examiner’s office for further investigation. <br> <em> Photo by Garrett Milanovich </em></p></div>
```

The following jquery fixed the problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.ui-link').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a meta tag in HTML page should solve the problem.

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />`